# My contacts aren't showing anymore

Tags: contacts

I have a big issue with my contacts. My database contains all of the correct information. I have checked it all in phpMyAdmin. Out of no where, when I search for contacts in Civi, it comes up with 0 contacts. It's like they all got deleted automatically. Please help!!

Comment: We need much more information than this. "Out of no where" sounds very unlikely.  Do you have logging enabled? Can you look in the log_civicrm_contacts to see who made the last change to the contacts and when and what it was.  What has been changed on your system since you last could "see" the contacts.  (Added an extension for your CMS?, upgraded?, your host changed something?)  Also what version of Civicrm are you on and what CMS and version are you using? Exactly how are you searching (perhaps an advanced search with something ticked in a one of the search windows that you aren't aware of?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you enabled "Contact Trash and Undelete" for your site?  If so, have you tried searching in Trash for contacts? Do an Advanced search and tick the "Search in Trash" box. It will be on the right side of the Basic Criteris search pane.  Exactly where depends on what version of CiviCRM you are using - which is why I have asked for that information.

Do you have logging enabled? Can you look in the log_civicrm_contacts to see who made the last change to the contacts and when and what it was.

"Out of no where" sounds improbable.

What has been changed on your system since you last could "see" the contacts. (Added an extension for your CMS?, upgraded?, your host changed something?)

Comment: I do not know how to check the log but all I know is I have only one person adding contacts. It was all working properly. I just do a Find Contacts, and then click the search button and all of them would show up. But now it was literally out of nowhere, I logged in and and I can't see any contacts. I had about 250 and now all I have is a couple in the system. Please help. I can give you all of my user info and log in information if needed to check it out

Comment: Also, when I log into Civi, it tells me that Timestamps reported by MySQL and PHP are mismatched. Is that something I have to fix?

Comment: @ElanKvitko, I have added instruction to this post about searching in trash. How about you answer the rest of the questions against the original post. (including version of CiviCRM, CMS type and version.)    Also, unless your site has been hacked, "literally out of nowhere" is an empty protestation.  Ask everyone who has access to you site what changes they made in the relevant time frame.

Comment: I don't know who you are or where you came from but did you know you're a genius?!? You're the absolute best!!!! THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!!!!! They somehow ended up in the trash!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried searching for other things like activities or contributions? If you get results for activities then likely your contacts are there.  If not (and there not in trash) then likely they are not.